# Error wil generating the schema fils for a mongodb data base with cubejs and mongobi

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cube.js

I am beginner into mongodb and big data systems.
I try to develop a dashboard for an application that I develop locally. Using cubejs and mongodb for BI, by following the following [blog](https://cube.dev/blog/building-mongodb-dashboard-using-node.js) :
I install the cubejs by : `npm install -g cubejs-cli`
After that, I create the backend cubejs project by : `cubejs create mongo-tutorial -d mongobi`
After moving into the project folder by `cd mongo-tutorial`, When I try to generate my schema by `cubejs generate -t zips` that give me the following out puts with an error :

```
(node:28896) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'INVALID_ALT_NUMBER' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:28896) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'INVALID_ALT_NUMBER' of module exports inside circular dependency
- Fetching DB schema
- Generating schema files
Cube.js Error ---------------------------------------
@cubejs-backend/schema-compiler/scaffolding/ScaffoldingTemplate dependency not found. Please run this command from project directory.
Need some help? -------------------------------------
  Ask this question in Cube.js Slack: https://slack.cube.dev
  Post an issue: https://github.com/cube-js/cube.js/issues
```

Data base information in .env file :

```
CUBEJS_DB_HOST=localhost
CUBEJS_DB_NAME=test
CUBEJS_DB_PORT=3307
CUBEJS_DB_TYPE=mongobi
CUBEJS_API_SECRET=62d555e33c215f1550d000e9b63755eaab68ffe7930545ce02775d315bbb2673ea65fdaf1d59f3c5653814367b25110ce2e214d07cb7b47958c58c8ffc0fb3
```

I import data by : `mongoimport.exe --db test --collection zips –file zips.json`
The data base is downloaded from : `https://media.mongodb.org/zips.json`
Screen capture of my compass tool:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZTeL.png)
Screen capture of my mongo bi:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oumY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug. We’ve prepared the `v0.23.10` release with a fix for it. Please upgrade your Cube.js CLI. Thanks.

Comment: I can generate the schema from the user interface, it works fine. ok i well upgrade thank allot.